# Why does flexbox change my div’s width with specific value

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to use flex layout to make a login content, it's just like an icon and an input in one row. I set `width:20px` and `height:20px` with icon and `width:100%` of input. I think it will make input to cover all the rest width except the specific value. The result is the size of icon changed.

With further learning about `flex`, I know another ways to achieve, such as `flex:1` with input or setting `min-width/height` of icon, but I just want to know why the `width:100%` affect size of sibling icon.

```css
.parent {
  width: 72%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: block;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
}

.login::placeholder {
  width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <input class="login" placeholder="place input your invite code" />
</div>
```

In this case, the size of `.icon` became `23.33*24`, both `width` and `height` changed.

Comment: first set `box-sizing: border-box` to take border into the width calculation - now again the width is less than 20px... this is because by default `flex-shrink` value is 1 (`width: 100%` of the input will shrink the `icon`) - so use `flex-shrink: 0`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**. Your `width` and `height` modifications aren't actually coming from flexbox, but rather due to the calculations derived from `width: 72%` in conjunction with the borders. Note that if you take away the `border: 2px solid green` on `.icon`, the `.icon` `height` will return to the specified `20px`.

If you want to prevent these adjustments, you can set `box-sizing: border-box`, which will make the `.icon`'s `20px` `width` **include** all border and padding calculations:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border: box;
}
```

I would recommend applying this to *all* elements with the global selector `*`, 
Setting this is often actually *recommend* due to the fact that it makes element size calculations easier to work with, and in fact this declarations is included by default in most frameworks.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 72%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: block;
}

.login {
  width: 100%;
}

.login::placeholder {
  width: 91px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <input class="login" placeholder="place input your invite code" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes, i missed the border, `height` is due to border, but what influences `width`?